# How to show <b> and <i> in jtextarea java

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

My requirement is to add ""string"" and ""string"" tags only not formatting in the screen using shortcuts ctrl+b and ctrl+i

I used the below code to add italic and bold tags

```
    static void addBold1() {
    int end = 0;
    String text = ta_description.getText();
    String selectionStart = ta_description.getSelectedText();
    int index = ta_description.getText().indexOf(selectionStart, ta_description.getSelectionStart());
    int len = selectionStart.length();
    end = index + len;
   ta_description.insert("<b>", index);
   ta_description.insert("</b>", end + 3);
}
```

Where ta_description is the textarea. With this i can add bold tags when the textarea is opened but when i reopen the screen bold tags are not coming. I dont need editor and text pane. I need to solve this using jtextarea. Suggest some idea.

Comment: `JTextArea` doesn't support markup, you'd need to use `\n` for new lines or use a `JTextPane` instead...

Comment: Oh, and you will want to become VERY familiar with the [`Document` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#document), because that's where you should be applying markup

Comment: I need to show bold and break tags not formatting. Is that not supported by jtextarea

Comment: Oh, showing the text, yes, that's possible, showing the mark so that the text becomes **bold** isn't

Comment: No in textpane only it becomes bold but in textarea there is no way to show <b> and <i> tags

Comment: i need to show as in textarea "<b> பெங்களூர் 28-4-2014</b> <i> தினத்தந்தி</i>". This is what i need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69173/discussion-between-prasath-bala-and-madprogrammer).

Comment: Works fine for me, consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: *"No in textpane only it becomes bold"*  Not if [`setContentType("text/plain")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#setContentType-java.lang.String-) is called.

Answer (score 1):

This is achieved by using cdata tags at the start and end  as like below

```
   <![CDATA[ <b> பெங்களூர் 28-4-2014</b> <i> தினத்தந்தி</i>]]>
```